# Match url and redirect to url+/index.html in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, public

I want to redirect some links that point to my `public` folder in Rails.

For example:

`http://site.com/example` should redirect to `http://site.com/example/index.html`

I only want to do this for the content that is my public folder.

I tried this in the config/routes.rb file:

```
 match "*pages" => redirect("/%{pages}/index.html")
```

But it enters a redirect loop.
So `http://site.com/example` redirects to to `http://site.com/example/index.html` which also redirects to `http://site.com/example/index.html/index.html` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your solution, Create a page controller and define your page action

**for example**

your controller name is `PagesController`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def about_us
  end
end
```

create a folder in `views`, name is `pages` and create a file that name is about_us. (like - "about_us.html.erb" and write content.

**In your route file** define

```
match "/pages/about_us" => "pages#about_us", :as => :about_us"
```